# Abort package install if dependent package doesn't exist

Tags: managed-package, package

I'm trying to figure out the best way to prevent a managed package from being installed if another managed package isn't already installed.

I've looked at [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53140/dependent-package) which basically explains what I'm trying to do, however the answer just states to "warn the user in the AppExchange".

Is there a programatic way to prevent this (like doing something in an [InstallHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm))?

Comment: If the other managed package is a part of your managed package then it will not let the user install until they install the dependency. The problem is it does not tell them until a few steps in causing frustration for the end user.

Comment: @Eric There would still be messages in the AppExchange listing about the package requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Salesforce automatically prevents installation of a package if the organization it's being installed on doesn't have the required package(s).

I created a package from the app I'm working on and installed it on a fresh Salesforce org.  I received this message:

[image: A required package is missing]

I haven't been able to find any documentation that states that this will happen though.